# Rename nested field name using $rename in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new at learning MongoDB and I want to rename the "ratings" array of the "Jimmy" customer in the following:

```
{ 
   "CUSTOMER" : 
         { 
           "first name" : "Jimmy",
           "ratings" : [ 
                    { "increase" : { "rate" : 99 } }, 
                    { "increase" : { "rate2" : 20.5 } 
                  } 
            ] 
      } 
}
```

I have tried many ways such as

```
db.collection.update({"CUSTOMER.first name":"Jimmy"}, {$rename:{"CUSTOMER.ratings":"discountings"}});
```

This way separate the array and make it as a new customer. Meaning that the array goes out of the CUSTOMER document. Also, I did put the $ symbol prior to "ratings" and I know it is not the right way and in fact it gives error message "not be dynamic".

Also, I tried the following, but actually it is not right as we are asking as if we want to change the entire document name. It give error message "must be a string".

```
db.collection.update({"CUSTOMER.first name":"Jimmy"}, {$rename:{"CUSTOMER":{"ratings":"discountings"}});
```

To sum up, it is wanted to change "ratings" to "discountings".

Comment: what do you mean by *goes out of the CUSTOMER document* & *This way separate the array and make it as a new customer* ? Can you give use sample entire doc & desired o/p..

Comment: I meant,  it becomes like this, so ratings became out of the customer brackets. { "CUSTOMER" : { "first name" : "Jimmy", } } ratings" : [ { "increase" : { "rate" : 99 } }, { "increase" : { "rate2" : 20.5 } } ] }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're renaming embedded document, you need to use `.` notation not only in `key` but also in `value`.

```
db.collection.update({"CUSTOMER.first name":"Jimmy"}, {$rename:{"CUSTOMER.ratings":"CUSTOMER.discountings"}})
```

If you don't use `.` notation :

```
db.collection.update({"CUSTOMER.first name":"Jimmy"}, {$rename:{"CUSTOMER.ratings":"discountings"}});
```

then it would 
`{ $unset: {'CUSTOMER.ratings' : 1} }` and `{ $set: {'discountings' : '$CUSTOMER.ratings'} }`

**Ref :** [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/index.html#rename-a-field-in-an-embedded-document)